# How to implement Fragment and AppCompatActivity in a single activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cardview

I have implemented swipe in tablayout of my activity call Performance_Medicine

```
public class Performance_Medicine extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

       //Returning the layout file after inflating
       //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.performance_medicine, container, false);
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to implement cardview in same activity. But getting error
[like below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcVJM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to pass an instance of `Performance_Medicine` which extends `Fragment`. You need to pass in a context which you can do via `this.getActivity()` or `this.getContext()`. If you can pass the application context via a singleton or `this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` then you may be better off memory wise.

Comment: unreachable statement 
albumList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: That's because you are calling `return v` before you instantiate the list. So the function ends before you ever reach that statement.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Fragment has its own lifecycle, but it runs in the context of its host Activity, that means you can not use 'this' for getting the Context, instead you need to use getActivity(). Also, as sam_c says, in your onCreate() method, the last line of code must be the 'return...' since this method has the return type 'View', and if you call the return statement, the method won't execute anything after this. Hope this helps to clarify.